# To integrate revmob android in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, revmob

I have a game to develop in unity. But I don't know how to integrate `revmob` for `android` `application` in `unity`. And I search in Google but didn't got any good answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [official SDK for unity3d](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/unity.html) .This will definitely work. after integrating the rev mob you will have to test it on device (iOS and android)

Answer (score 0):

http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/unity.html#download .This is link for rev mob sdk for unity 3d.In this sdk There is a simple app integrate Revmob .You can test this sample scene on Andriod Or Iphone  device